# How to properly trasfer contextual action bar functionality to a toolbar

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an activity that shows some data on a listview. when one long press an item, i have implemented a toolbar that becomes visible and allows the user to perform some actions. i don't want this actions to be at contextual action bar since my actionbar displays some information that show not be overtaken by contextual action bar

When one long press a list item, my toolbar become visible and you can do some actions like deleting.

**desired output**

- contextual action bar should not show up when you long press a list item
- when you press your phone back button when you have not performed any action **but just selected list items**. list selection should dissapear **BUT NOT** exiting the activity

**Problems**

- after long pressing a list item, **contextual action bar appears**
- after performing the action(e.g delete), **contextual action bar still remains visible.**
- When i select list items and just click back button,**my activity is exited instead of just disselecting list selections**

**here's how am handling long clicks on my listview**

```
private class DataSelector implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener{
    android.view.ActionMode mode;
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        adapter.toggleSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        this.mode =mode;
        SelectionListener selectionListener = new SelectionListener();
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Button delete = (Button) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(selectionListener);
        return true;
    }

    private class SelectionListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        public void onClick(View v){
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.Delete:
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelecteItemsIds();
                    ArrayList<Long> dataIds = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i =(selected.size()-1); i>=0; i--){

                        if(selected.valueAt(i)){
                            int key = selected.keyAt(i);
                            d(" key is: " + key);
                            CountryData data = adapter.getItem(key);
                            long id = data.getId();

                            if(id != 0){
                                dataIds.add(id);
                            }
                            adapter.remove(data);
                        }
                    }
                    onDestroyActionMode(mode);

                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
      adapter.removeSelection();
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**Question**

how can i achieve the above desired output?

Comment: You should take the Stack Overflow tour @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour . The issue with your post is that you listed many problems and desired outputs and goals. The posts in Stack Overflow is meant to have a specific goal or an output, and NOT a project. Perhaps if you post a "bounty", you can get more attention but I doubted. Good luck anyway...

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid this are not many problems. solving issue of CAB solves all the others.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid    whatever i want to achieve is done by contextual action bar(CAB). i just want to handle it work on my toolbar